# Is there a reason to update statistics manually?

Tags: sql-server, index, statistics, maintenance

In SQL Server,  statistics are updated automatically when `Auto Update Statistics` in `True` (which is the default). Is there a reason to update statistics manually and in what circumstances?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure, if your data is changing more frequently than the rate of auto stats (or, say, you are updating < 20% of the rows frequently, like updating statuses or date/time stamps). Or if your table is huge and it is not changing enough to trigger auto stats updates. Or if you have filtered indexes ([since the auto stats threshold is still based on the % of change on the whole table, not the % of change of the subset of rows in the filtered index](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/509638/suggesting-change-to-filtered-statistics-updates)).

Comment: +1 for filtered indexes.  I think that's the main reason, or on VERY large data sets. I have tables that I insert 30m rows a month, but it's a small percentage so stats don't normally get updated unless I kick it off manually.

Comment: +1 Also, you do it on a schedule to reset the counters, means less chance outside your maintenance window.

Answer (score 7):

A couple more (superficial) reasons:

Auto-update stats will block the query that triggered the update until the new statistics are ready.

...Unless you also enable auto-update stats asynchronously. Then the query that triggered the update won't wait for the new stats, but will potentially run with the old, incorrect stats.

I also ran into some strange blocking issues when a database with some relatively large tables (44M rows, 8.5 GB) would start updating stats. We decommissioned that application before I was able to really track down what was going on, though.

Comment: +1 That's a great point about the blocking and the async option.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, remember that auto stats are always generated with a default sampling rate.
That default sampling rate may not accurately produce statistics that represent your data.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/elisabeth_redei/archive/2009/03/01/lies-damned-lies-and-statistics-part-i.aspx